# Use ReliableQueue in ServiceFabric without polling?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I've been looking at stateful services within Service Fabric. I've been digging through the examples, specifically the WordCount. They have a RunAsync method that looks like this inside of the WordCountService:

```
 protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IReliableQueue<string> inputQueue = await this.StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableQueue<string>>("inputQueue");

        while (true)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            try
            {
                using (ITransaction tx = this.StateManager.CreateTransaction())
                {
                    ConditionalValue<string> dequeuReply = await inputQueue.TryDequeueAsync(tx);

                    if (dequeuReply.HasValue)
                    {
                       //... {more example code here }
                    }
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                //Service Fabric uses timeouts on collection operations to prevent deadlocks.
                //If this exception is thrown, it means that this transaction was waiting the default
                //amount of time (4 seconds) but was unable to acquire the lock. In this case we simply
                //retry after a random backoff interval. You can also control the timeout via a parameter
                //on the collection operation.
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(new Random().Next(100, 300)));

                continue;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //For sample code only: simply trace the exception.
                ServiceEventSource.Current.MessageEvent(exception.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Essentially, in this example, the service is polling the ReliableQueue every 100ms for messages. Is there a way to do this without the poll? Can we subscribe to an event or something that gets triggered when a message is successfully added to the ReliableQueue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently there are no events you can use for ReliableQueue. You have to poll for new items.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there are any plans to expose any events? Or would I be better off subscribing to an Azure ServiceBus topic/queue if I wanted to avoid polling?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a [ReliableDispatcher](https://github.com/wc2/micro-service-fabric/wiki/Reliable-Dispatcher) in your service, or just use a [Dispatcher Service](https://github.com/wc2/micro-service-fabric/wiki/Dispatcher-Services).

Using the **Dispatcher Service** allows you to write a method that is invoked whenever an item is enqueued on the underlying reliable queue.

For example:

```
public override async Task OnItemDispatchedAsync(
    ITransaction transaction,
    int value,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Do something with the value that has been dequeued
}
```

Both the **Reliable Dispatcher** and **Dispatcher Service** can be used via a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MicroServiceFabric.Dispatcher/) and there's full documentation and samples on GitHub to get you started:

- Example of using [Dispatcher Service](https://github.com/wc2/micro-service-fabric/blob/master/Samples/CounterApp_StatefulDispatcherService/CounterService/CounterService.cs)
- Example of using [Reliable Dispatcher](https://github.com/wc2/micro-service-fabric/blob/master/Samples/CounterApp_ReliableDispatcher/CounterService/CounterService.cs)